# Error: UnsatisfiedDependencyException with mySQL

Tags: java, spring, maven

I make by my own shema in MySQL, named project, and I have following code and following error, and don't know how to fix it. Please if you help me. It is my first project like this, i already tried everything I founded on stackoverflow

Service:

```
  package service;

    import java.util.List;

    import model.User;

    public interface UserService {
        public User findOne(Long id);
        public List<User> find();
        public User save(User user);
        public void delete(User user);
        public User update(User newUser, Long userId);
        public User findByUsername(String username);

    }

Implementation of service:




 import java.util.List;

    import javax.transaction.Transactional;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

    import model.User;
    import repository.UserRepository;
    import service.UserService;
    @Service
    @Transactional
    public class UserServiceJpa implements UserService {
        @Autowired
        private UserRepository userRepository;

        @Override
        public User findOne(Long id) {
            User user = userRepository.findOne(id);

            return user;
        }

        @Override
        public List<User> find() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return userRepository.findAll();
        }
    //...
    }
```

Repository:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import model.User;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{
    public User findByUsername(String username);

    public User findOne(Long id);
}
```

Model class:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    private long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private UserType type;
    private String dateOfReg;
    private ProfileUser profile;

    public User() {
    }
    //...
    }
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>project</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>codehaus</id>
            <url>http://repository.codehaus.org/org/codehaus</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.useSSL=false

sping.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=50
spring.jpa.hibernate.connection.CharSet=utf8
spring.jpa.hibernate.connection.characterEncoding=utf8
spring.jpa.hibernate.connection.useUnicode=true
```

---

error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method
>   'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class:
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]     at
>   com.example.Sbz3Application.main(Sbz3Application.java:10)
>   [classes/:na] Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method
>   'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class:
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   ... 28 common frames
>   omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method
>   'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class:
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   ... 41 common frames
>   omitted Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver
>   class: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver   at
>   org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:70)
>   ~[spring-core-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:231)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder(DataSourceProperties.java:183)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:42)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:56)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source) ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   ... 42 common frames
>   omitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project is using Mysql5.1, and the Driver class you are attempting to load does not exist there (com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver). 
See if this helps - change the application.properties line from

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

to

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```